# Android save login user details in application

Tags: android, web-services, android-logcat

I am a web developer and new to android and studying ... For first step I made an user login system using PHP-MySQL web services.

The application communicating with the web service pretty well and check for user exists. Now if the user exists it will return the user details if user exists.

My question is like in web application is there any session / cookie handling in android application ? For eg if I can save the session then not need to login at each and every time.

I am sure there is a way to do this because lots of apps are working with this feature. But since I am new to android please advice a bit.

Not knowing a correct word to googling. Is that "SavePreferences".

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). This stores data persistently in a (key, value) pair so you could say have a check box at the login screen so if they check it then it stores a `boolean` as the `value` and their username as the `key`. Then when they get to the login screen and choose their username it checks that value and if it is `true` then it doesn't require a password. This is assuming that you allow more than one user to login from the app.

However, if you only have one person logging in from the app to that device, then you could send back a value from the web server when they open the app that they can skip the login screen.

Besides the links to the docs I provided above, [Here is a good example in the docs to get you started](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

If you are in need of something more robust than what SharedPreferences provides, then look at the [Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) section of the docs. Hope this helps

**Retrieve prefs**

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("john smith", 0);
    saved= (prefs.getString("loginSaved", false));  
if (saved)
  // do stuff here
else
  // require login
```

Comment: So if the user opt in for saving his login, the app would automatically choose his username and password again and send it off to be authenticated?

Comment: Sure, depending on how you are doing your authentication, you can open up your `SharedPrefs` and if the value is `true` (they checked a box to remember them the first time) then you can pass whatever info you need to the server that may be stored in another `SharedPrefs`, DB, or whatever

Comment: Would this work for multiple users on the same device, or I would need to set up a new prefs for each.

Comment: You could make it work for all but for security reasons I would think you would want to set up a separate prefs for each

Comment: Have any links that would show supporting for multiple user prefs, or just a a quick snippet? ^_^

Comment: thanks for your comments.. by the way how to retrieve the saved values into my application ?

Comment: I have added a short example of how to retrieve them after set. The docs link i provided shows an example of how to use them. As far as multiple users...you could have a different pref according to the user name. Please accept if this helped

Answer (score 0):

SharedPreferences is what you're looking for!

Check out this code to learn more about how to use it:

http://kettiandroidproject.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Private/Earthquake/src/com/company/earthquake/Preferences.java