# android - how to remember the account for an app?

Tags: android

What is a good way to remember the account for an app in the client side as I want to the user to login to update their information. But, typing user account and password is quite annoying when the user uses the app.

Is it good to store the unique ID for a user account(or uses account directly) in the client side so that the user doesn't need to type account and password every time by taking the data for login automatically when the app is activated. If it is secure enough to do so, how to write the code? Please demonstrate the simple code or a part of code. Thank you.

---

I am a beginner of app development. What is the shared preference and how to the code? Can you show me some code or website?

Comment: I appreciate for the answers with explanation from all guys. But, I feel sorry that I can select only one as the best answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android save login user details in application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16381147/android-save-login-user-details-in-application)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provide a checkbox `Remember me`

Copy and paste below code to your `onCreate`

```
SharedPreferences myPref = =  getSharedPreferences("APP_SHARED_PREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String username= myPref.getString("username","");
        String password= myPref.getString("password",""); 
        isCheckedRemeber = myPref.getBoolean("checkstatus",false);
```

above code will check stored values in `SharedPreferences`

Change the check status of `CheckBox` and set the values to `EditText`(username ,password)

When you press Login button(Login button Action)

```
if(isCheckedRemeber) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myPref.edit();
            editor.putString("username", username);
            editor.putString("password", password);//encript if you need to secure it
            editor.putBoolean("checkstatus", isCheckedRemeber);
            editor.commit();
        }
```

Comment: @KeroroChan Happy to help

Comment: btw, What is commit()?

Comment: Commit your preferences changes back from this Editor to the SharedPreferences object it is editing.

Comment: read more from [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html)

Comment: second parameter is the default value,ie ,if the shared preference is empty return string initialized with second parameter

Answer (score 4):

Simplest way is to store the User details in the shared preference. When the user opens the app check sharedPreference data and launch the appropriate screen. If you have user details you can directly take them to the home page. If any data is changed you can update the sharedPreference and use that data.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is a good idea to store the UserID on the client side using shared Preferences. Like this:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = a.getSharedPreferences("myData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("userID", "SomeUserID");
editor.putString("userPassword", "SomeUserPass"); // think of encryption here
editor.commit();
```

Then on your start page:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = a.getSharedPreferences("myData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String userID = null;
        String password = null;
        if(prefs.contains("userID")) {
            userID = prefs.getString("userID", null);
            password = prefs.getString("userPassword", null)
        }
```

Only root access users can see the files stored in the private app storage.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a good idea to store the login credentials for the user in his/her respective device (once the user has successfully log in the app).

In order to achieve this, you can use `SharedPreferences` interface. The `SharedPreferences` are used for storing, accessing and modifying preference data in the app.

To create a `SharedPreferences` object, you need to use the getSharedPreferences() method as shown below. It has two arguments:

1. Name of the Preferences file.
2. Mode in which you want to open the file.

   `SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("name", MODE_PRIVATE);`

You will need the `SharedPreferences.Editor` object to make any changes to the data stored in any `Preferences` file. Create the `Editor` object as shown below.

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
```

Now, to store any data in the `Preferences` file we will use the editor object created above. **All data stored to any Preferences file is stored in form of key and value pairs.** For the sake of explanation, lets take an example where you need to store a String "abc" to the Preferences file. The code will be as follows:

```
editor.putString("key", "value");
```

**Note that, you have to commit all your changes to the Preferences file.** If you do not commit, your changes will not be saved. To commit changes:

```
editor.commit();
```

To retrieve the String, we will need the key with which the String was stored in the `Preferences` file as shown below.

```
sharedPreferences.getString("key", "default_value");
```

The second argument in the above method is the default value in our example. **This method will return the default value if any Preference with the specified key does not exist.**

Comment: The second argument in the above method is the default value which in our example. This method will return the default value if any Preference with the specified key does not exist. I love that.

Comment: The explanation is great!

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is to store the User details in the shared preference.When you login and get the Username and Password then it store in shared preference like this

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(Constant.PREFERENCE_NAME, 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
editor.putString("UserName", str_userName);
editor.putString("Password", str_password);
editor.commit();
```

And When you app Load (Like SplashScreen is load) then you can get data from Share Preference like this.

```
SharedPreferences sp1=getSharedPreferences(Constant.PREFERENCE_NAME,0);
String unm=sp1.getString("UserName", "");
String pass = sp1.getString("Password", "");

if(unm.length()>0 && pass.length()>0){
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Home.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
else
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Login.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

as @madhuri suggested you can do it with using `SharedPreferences`.

I am gonna give my example the way i implement this functionality.

### **First of all How to use `SharedPreferences`**

define `SharedPreferences` :

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

edit `SharedPreferences` :

```
SharedPreferences.Editor edit= sharedPreferences.edit();
edit.putString("email", someText);
edit.putString("pass", someText);
edit.commit();
```

fatching value from `SharedPreferences` :

```
String email = sharedPreferences.getString("email", null);
```

### **Now let's see an Example :**

I made one SplashScreen for checking whether my preference has values or not. and here is how i check.

**Splash.java**

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String email = sharedPreferences.getString("email", null);
String pass = sharedPreferences.getString("pass", null);

if (name == null || pass == null) {
    Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, LogInPage.class);
    startActivity(i);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);
    finish();
} else {
    Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);
    finish();
}
```

**LoginPage.java**

now after successfully login you have to store values in `SharedPreferences`.

```
if(loginSuccess){
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit= sharedPreferences.edit();
    edit.putString("email", someText);
    edit.putString("pass", someText);
    edit.commit();

    Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);
    finish();
}
```

I hope it is clear.

Happy Coding..

Comment: Thank you for giving practical examples.

Answer (score 0):

Putting data in the sharedpreferences is the best efficient way. Store User Id and password in the sharedpreference. When the app is opened just check that whether sharedpref contains ID. If yes then directly set text from shared pref to respective edittext.